# Saving datetime into timestamp column

Tags: mysql, node.js, momentjs

I am using momentjs to calculate datetime:

```
moment().add(24, 'h').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

But I get this error when saving in MYSQL **timestamp** column:

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '_isUTC' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Let us see your INSERT statement. Obviously there are no such column in your field list.

Comment: `expiry` = '\"2016-06-30T07:58:18.326Z\"',

Comment: "datetime" and "timestamp" in Mysql have same format: `1970-12-21 23:59:59`; convert your date before insert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

use `moment().add(24, 'h').toISOString()`

Comment: moment(...).add(...).format(...).toISOString is not a function